# Revolution of a 2D polar plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surface

I want to perform a 360° revolution of the following 2D polar plot, around the 0° direction axis:

[image]
I do not have an analytical function describing it (e.g. f = R(theta)), but only two discrete arrays: the radius values and the angles theta

Let R be the vector containing the radii value of the polar plot:

```
  xv = R.* cos(theta);  % // Polar to 2D Cartesian coordinates
  yv = R.* sin(theta);  % // Polar to 2D Cartesian coordinates
  
  phi = 0:.001:2*pi;        % // 3D revolution angle around theta = 0

  % // 3D points of the surface

  xf = repmat(xv',size(phi)); 
  yf = yv' * cos(phi);
  zf = yv' * sin(phi);
  
mesh(xf,yf,zf)
```

The code here above plots this:

[image]

[image]

It seems correct, *but*:

1. The *zf* values (see colorbar) are in a different range than what I would expect from a simple 360° revolution of the polar plot. And that's because *zf* is the result of the coordinates transformation.
2. The way the colormap algorithm works, it assigns a color depending on the magnitude of *zf* from the origin. This means that the way the surface is colored now has nothing to do with the actual magnitude of *zf*. For instance, there are no negative values in the 2D polarplot, while the revolution obviously generates points that have negative coordinates with respect to the reference frame origin.

It should be a straightforward operation, but I am somehow stuck...

Thank you for any insight on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mesh` command accepts [another argument to define colors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html): One way is defining a color for each vertex, and in your case you can still make use of the automatic colormap by using using the radius `R` as a color:

```
mesh(xf,yf,zf, repmat(R', size(phi)))
```